# How to find documents by multiple conditions for one field with QueryBuilderAPI in Doctrine MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, symfony, query-builder

I have a data model in MongoDB which I can successfully query by native MongoDB queries. However I'm not able to express them with the Query Builder API of Doctrine MongoDB ODM.

This is how my **model** looks in MongoDB (this is some example JSON-Code):

```
{ "name": "ArticleName", 
  "features": {
    { "type": "color",
      ...
      "values": {
        { "value": "RED", 
          "label": "red",
          ....
        },

        { "value": "GREEN", 
          "label": "green" }
      } 
    },
    { "type": "width",
      "values": {
        { "value": "40"}
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I want to **find articles by searching for different feature-value combinations**, e.g. I want to find an article with color=green and width=40.

However, I was not able to build a query for that with the Doctrine MongoDB ODM Query Builder API**? This is what I tried:

```
# Document/ArticleRepository.php    

$features = array('color'=>'RED', 'width'=>'40');
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('CatalogBundle:Article'); // I use symfony 2
foreach ($features as $type => $value)
{
    $qb->field('features')->elemMatch(
        $qb->expr()->field('type')->equals($type)->field('values')->elemMatch(
            $qb->expr()->field('value')->equals($value)
        )
    );
}
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

However this does result into a query, which contains only one condition. The other condition seems to be overwritten. This is the **query generated by the Query Builder**:

```
db.articles.find({ "features": { "$elemMatch": { "type": "width", "values": { "$elemMatch": { "value": 40 } } } } })
```

**Is there a way to solve my use case with the MongoDB ODM Query Builder API?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I meanwhile solved my problem by using the **$all-Operator**. I build an array of Expressions, which are passed to the Doctrine MongoDB `all()`-Method. The strategy with `$elemMatch` I tried above would not even have worked with MongoDB. You have to add **->getQuery()** at end to be able to write the expression to an array. For some reason **expressions are not yet documented**, however you can check their functionality in the **[source code](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Expr.php)**.

```
# Document/ArticleRepository.php

$features = array('color'=>'RED', 'width'=>'40');
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('CatalogBundle:Article');
$all_features[] = array();

foreach ($features as $templateID => $value)
{
    # Add expression as a subquery to array
    $all_features[] = $qb->expr()->elemMatch(
        $qb->expr()->field('templateID')->equals($templateID)->field('values')->elemMatch(
            $qb->expr()->field('value')->equals($value)
        )
    )->getQuery();
}
# Add expressions to query
$qb->field('features')->all($all_features);
```

An expression supports pretty much all methods you can use when building a query. You can build your MongoDB request by interlacing several expressions. This allows you to **build complex MongoDB Queries** you could build otherwise only by passing an array to the `findBy()`-Method. However with the current version (Beta 2) of the Doctrine ODM this strategy would not allow you to add more methods to the MongoDB chain, like `.limit()`.

**So expressions look like the best strategy to build complex queries with Doctrine MongoDB.**

Comment: Looks much more complex than building the query directly.